# Android preview window doesn't display gridding

Tags: android

I am newly developing android app in android studio. I learn by watching teaching video.

In the video, I saw gridding on the preview. However, no gridding on my preview window(as displayed  in the pic below)

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: can show preview which you expected?

Comment: Yes! But I want to know dp of every layout so that I can design better

Comment: I want it to show gridding in the preview not in the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try with picking lowest **"emulator preview version"** it is available above the preview console